# Cannot borrow `polygon_vertex_count` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust code:

```
    #[test]
    fn split_in_half_test() {
        let vertices = [
            Vector3 { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0 },
            Vector3 { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0 },
            Vector3 { x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 },
            Vector3 { x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0 },
        ];
        let mut polygon = FPoly::new();
        polygon.vertices[.. 4].copy_from_slice(vertices.as_slice());
        polygon.vertex_count = 4;

        let other_polygon = polygon.split_in_half(); // split_in_half modifies the original `polygon` and returns a new one

        assert_eq!(3, polygon.vertex_count, "Mismatching vertex count for original polygon");
        assert_eq!(3, other_polygon.vertex_count, "Mismatching vertex count for the new split polygon");
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `polygon.vertex_count` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src\lib.rs:179:9
    |
177 |         let other_polygon = polygon.split_in_half(); // split_in_half modifies the original `polygon` and returns a new one
    |                             ----------------------- mutable borrow occurs here
178 |
179 |         assert_eq!(3, polygon.vertex_count, "Mismatching vertex count for original polygon");
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
180 |         assert_eq!(3, other_polygon.vertex_count, "Mismatching vertex count for the new split polygon");
    |         ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- mutable borrow later used here
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

The function signature of `split_in_half` is:

```
pub fn split_in_half(&mut self) -> FPoly
```

I don't understand why this is happening since, if I comment out either one of the assertion statements, it compiles and runs fine. But the two of them are referencing different objects. How is this possible?

Where `FPoly` is defined like this:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct FPoly<'a> {
    vertices: [Vector3<f32>; FPOLY_MAX_VERTICES],
    vertex_count: usize,
    item_name: &'a str,
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't answer my question. I was able to have this run by simply reversing the order of the assert lines but I have no idea why that works. I have updated the question to include the type definition for `FPoly`.

Comment: We don't need the full definition but a [mre] of it. It works because of non lexical lifetimes. The other version doesn't because your `other_polygon`s lifetime is bound to `polygons` by ommiting the lifetime of `FPoly` in the function signature. This type most definitely should not implement `Copy` as it's huge.

Comment: Using a lifetime here is debatable. You should really consider using `String` (or `Box<str>`, or even `Arc<str>` if the name is shared a lot) instead. It'll simplify your code, and most probably you won't feel the perf hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your method is the elided lifetime:

```rust
pub fn split_in_half(&mut self) -> FPoly
```

is the short form of

```rust
pub fn split_in_half<'a>(&'a mut self) -> FPoly<'a>
```

So you see by not specifying a more apropriate lifetime, `FPoly` implicitly depends on the duration of the borrow on `self`.

What you probably want is something like this:

```rust
impl FPoly<'_> {
    pub fn split_in_half(&mut self) -> Self {
        //…
    }
}
```

where using `Self` makes sure that the lifetimes of both the argument and the returned type are the same, but notably the lifetime of the mutable borrow is something different.

i.e. the elided lifetimes and all short forms like `Self` all written explicitly it's equivalent to:

```rust
impl<'a> FPoly<'a> {
    fn split_in_half<'b>(self: &'b mut FPoly<'a>) -> FPoly<'a> {
        //…
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is why you should always at least [`#![warn(elided_lifetimes_in_paths)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths) (I `#![forbid(rust_2018_idioms)]` on every new project).